# LaTeX - add prefix to a single label in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

Using the following code, I am able to print one question of a multiple-choice test.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Which of the following words begins with s?
    \begin{enumerate}[a)]
      \item Earth
      \item Brown
      \item Saturday
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like to prefix the label for the correct answer by a single character (and potentially a few spaces for separating the character and the label).

The result should look like this:

```
1. Which of the following words begins with s?
   a) Earth
   b) Brown
-  c) Saturday
```

Ideally I would like to use something like `\prefixeditem` for the correct choice instead of `\item` to achieve this.

I know that it is possible to replace the label completely by `\item [-]`, but I wasn't able to find a way how to just add a prefix.

I also tried using package *exam*, but unfortunately it doesn't allow modifications of labels.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thorough enough. MWE should be correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\prefixeditem}{\item\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$\hspace*{1cm}}}
\begin{document}
  Which of the following words begins with s?
  \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item Earth
    \item Brown
    \prefixeditem Saturday
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if you want a version that doesn't have the answers marked, you can just use `\newcommand{\prefixeditem}{\item}`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a suboptimal solution. There is already a better answer here, but someone might find this useful:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Which of the following words begins with s?
    \begin{labeling}{~~~a)}
      \item[~~~a)] Earth
      \item[~~~b)] Brown
      \item[-~~c)] Saturday
    \end{labeling}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```